# Why Zsh terminal icons are not getting displayed in Atom Platformio Ide Terminal?

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, manjaro, gnome-terminal, atom-editor

[image]

I’m running Atom on Manjaro Linux. And I installed Platformio Ide Terminal. Everything is working fine, except the Zsh shell icons. None of the icons is getting displayed. Only boxes like you can see in the screenshot. I’m running Gnome Desktop Environment. Everything is fine in Zsh shell I get in the `gnome-terminal`

Here is a screenshot of the same commands executed in the `gnome-terminal`
[image]

**What’s wrong with the terminal in Atom? What can be done to make it look like the `gnome-terminal`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a font that contains all the icons you want. If in doubt, `gnome-terminal`'s profile settings show you the font it uses.

Use that same font in your IDE. (I don't know Atom Platformia IDE, but I bet the terminal font either configurable through some dialogue or just a setting in a CSS file somewhere.)

Comment: It did the trick. `NotoSansMono Nerd Font` in my case. Thaks for the help man :)